# Confusing with the usage of regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm confused with the following three patterns, would someone explain it in more detail?

```
## IPython with Python 2.7.3
In [62]: re.findall(r'[a-z]*',"f233op")
Out[62]: ['f', '', '', '', 'op', '']  ## why does the last '' come out?

In [63]: re.findall(r'([a-z])*',"f233op")
Out[63]: ['f', '', '', '', 'p', '']  ## why does the character 'o' get lost?

In [64]: re.findall(r'([a-z]*)',"f233op")
Out[64]: ['f', '', '', '', 'op', '']  ## what's the different than line 63 above?
```

Comment: The middle one is a bit confusing to me.  The other 2 make sense though.

Comment: Try change `*` to `+` and possibly you wont get the empty ones (i'm not a python dev tho)

Comment: Great question! The '\*' operator will often produce surprising results when used in the context of 'greedy' search patterns like the ones above. In fact, since '\*' matches 0 or more occurrences of a given expression, the result list could contain an infinite amount of empty ('') matches and still be a valid result! The fact that the first regex produces an empty match at the end of the sequence has probably to do with the particular implementation of the state machine that is produced when the regex gets compiled (this will need some more investigation though).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Example 1

```
re.findall(r'[a-z]*',"f233op")
```

This pattern is matching zero-or-more instances of lower case alphabet characters.  The ZERO-or-more part is key here, since a match of nothing, starting from every index position in the string, is just as valid as a match of `f` or `op`.  The last empty string returned is the match starting from the end of the string (the position between `p` and `$` (end of string).

#### Example 2

```
re.findall(r'([a-z])*',"f233op")
```

Now you are matching character groups, consisting of a single lower-case alphabet character.  The `o` is no longer returned because this is a greedy search, and the last valid matched group will be returned.  So if you changed the string to `f233op12fre`, the final `e` would be returned, but no the preceding `f` or `r`.  Likewise, if you take out the `p` in your string, you still see that `o` is returned as a valid match.

Conversely, if you tried to make this regex non-greedy by adding a `?` (eg. `([a-z])*?`), the returned set of matches would all be empty strings, since a valid match of nothing has a higher precedence of a valid match of something.

#### Example 3

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]*)',"f233op")
```

Nothing is different in the matched characters, but now you are returning character groups instead of raw matches.  The output of this regex query will be the same as your first example, but you'll notice that if you add an additional matching group, you will suddenly see the results of each match attempt grouped into tuples:

```
IN : re.findall(r'([a-z]*)([0-9]*)',"f233op")
OUT: [('f', '233'), ('op', ''), ('', '')]
```

Contrast this with the same pattern, minus the parenthesis (groups), and you'll see why they are important:

```
IN : re.findall(r'[a-z]*[0-9]*',"f233op")
OUT: ['f233', 'op', '']
```

#### Also...

It can be useful to plug regex patterns like these into regex diagram generators like [Regexplained](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/) to see how the pattern matching logic works.  For example, as an explanation as to why your regex is always returning empty character string matches, take a look at the difference between the patterns [`[a-z]*`](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/?pattern=%5Ba-z%5D*) and [`[a-z]+`](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/?pattern=%5Ba-z%5D%2B).

Don't forget to check the [Python docs for the `re` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) if you get stuck, they actually give a pretty stellar explanation for the standard regex syntax.

Comment: Awesome explanation for each pattern! Thanks very much for the updating about the greedy and non-greedy concept!

Comment: can you explain the empty string matches from regex #2?

Comment: @FlipMcF: All of these regex queries basically translate to "return all matches of zero-or-more lowercase alphabet characters".  The regex engine will walk through the string and return all non-overlapping substrings that fit this criteria.  Since the starting position of every regex match attempt is always between characters, and an empty string is a valid match in these patterns, empty strings will be returned for each position that a match was attempted.

Comment: Very good example as `re.findall(r'([a-z]*)([0-9]*)',"f233op")`. re.findall(...) returns character group(s), and more than one group are presented in the pattern, the result will be a list of tuples. When the engine goes over `f233op` with the pattern `([a-z]*)([0-9]*)`, it first hits `f` ( with pattern ([a-z]*) ), then it meets `233`( with pattern ([0-9]*), since it's greedy, matches digits as many as possible), afterwards, `f` and `233` are grouped together as a tuple -> ('f', '233'). Likewise, `([a-z]*)` matches `op`, `([0-9]*)` matches ''.  Do I express the matching logic correct so far?

Comment: BUT, I'm wondering how does `('', '')` come out with `re.findall(r'([a-z]*)([0-9]*)',"f233op")` ??  When `('op', '')` is returned, in my option, it already reached the end of the string `f233op`. Would you please correct me, if I misunderstand this point.

Comment: @vicd: `('op', '')` is the result of the match that starts between `3` and `o`, while `('', '')` is the result of the match that starts from between `p` and `$` (end of line).  It helps to think of regex matches as always starting and ending between characters (including `^` and `$`).  To illustrate, look at the result of `re.findall('[a-z]*?', 'abc')`.  It is four empty strings.

Comment: Although it is a little bit bewildering for me, I think I got it, finally. I will spend some time to digest it, lot of information these days :D Thanks for the gorgeous explanation again!

Answer (score 6):

1. You get the final `''` because `[a-z]*` is matching the empty string at the end.
2. The character `'o'` is missing because you have told `re.findall` to match *groups*, and each group has a single character.  Put another way, you’re doing the equivalent of

   ```
   m = re.match(r'([a-z])*', 'op')
   m.group(1)
   ```

   which will return `'p'`, because that’s the last thing captured by the parens (capture group 1).
3. Again, you’re matching groups, but this time multi-character groups.

Comment: This still doesn't completely do it for me.  Where did the `o` go?  Why not `['f', '', '', '', 'o', 'p', '']`?

Comment: @mgilson Because of the way groups match in regular expressions.  If I match something like this: `([a-z])*` against a string, then the capture value for group 1 will be the *last* instance that matched.  i.e. matching against `'foobar'`, I will get `'r'`.

Comment: If you want 1 char per "match", why are you using '*'?

Comment: @alastair Exactly, it's because '\*' is a greedy operator. '*?' would match the first occurence instead.

Comment: @ThePhysicist: Actually, it is important to note in this case, using `[a-z]*?` would return a set of empty strings, since a valid match of nothing has higher precedence than a valid match of something.

Comment: Oh good point, damn it! Probably it would be more adequate to use [a-z]+ then in this case, which returns ['f','op']. After all these years, regexes still defeat me...

Answer (score 2):

Your surprising results are related to the Regular Expression Quantifier `*`.

Consider:

```
[a-z]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YBDzadvXGTfIDaci)

Vs:

```
[a-z]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/K2Bukobv3YIH8Kh2)

Consider as another example that I think is more illustrative of what you are seeing:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]*', '123456789')
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

There are no characters in the set `[a-z]` in the string `123456789`. Yet, since `*` means '**zero** or more', *all* character *positions* 'match' by not matching any characters at that position.

For example, assume you just wanted to test if there were any letters in a string, and you use a regex like so:

```
>>> re.search(r'[a-z]*', '1234')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1069b6988>     # a 'match' is returned, but this is 
                                           # probably not what was intended
```

---

Now consider:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]*', '123abc789')
['', '', '', 'abc', '', '', '', '']
```

Vs:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([a-z])*', '123abc789')
['', '', '', 'c', '', '', '', '']
```

The first pattern is `[a-z]*`. The part `[a-z]` is a character class matching a *single character* in the set `a-z` unless modified; the addition of `*` quantifier will greedily match as many characters as possible if more than zero -- hence the match of 'abc' but will also allow zero characters to be a match (or a character outside the character set to match the position since 0 is a match).

The addition of a grouping in `([a-z])*` effectively reduces the match in the quantified set back to a single character and the last character matched in the set is returned.

If you want the effect of grouping (say in a more complex pattern) use a non capturing group:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:[a-z])*', '123abc789')
['', '', '', 'abc', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Very clear and helpful explanation, I'm trying to express my understanding to make sure I got this point. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Take the `re.findall(r'([a-z])*', '123abc789')` for example, the pattern `'([a-z])*'`, it consists of a lower-case character in the group, and `*` tells that search the group(1 character group) as many as possible. So when it goes over `abc`, it first fetches `a`, it matches the pattern, but it greedily finds that `b` also matches the pattern, then it drops `a`, and then, it fetches the new character `c` as the replacement of `b`. it goes on `7` afterwards, but it only gets a match of '' since `7` is not a char.

Comment: Yes, more or less. Try `re.findall(r'([a-z])', '123abc789')` for a third variant.

Comment: for the pattern `([a-z])`, it consists of `EXACT` one-lowercase-alphabetic character group, so when it goes through the string `123abc789`, any non-lowercase-alphabetic character is dropped (such as 1,2,3,7,8,9), and the first match is found when it hits `a`, no greedy is specified, it will not try any further search, so `a` is returned as a part of list. Likewise, `b` and `c` are appended to the result list --> `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Correct. :-) Just spend some time with some of the regex demo thingies (like Debuggex or regex101) and this will be easy!

Comment: Fantastic tools online, I like regex101 more :-), nice and clean. The statechart shown on Debuggex seems a little abstract for me, although it presents quit well too :P

Answer (score 1):

In line 63 you're finding all instances of a group (indicated with the parens) of characters of length 1.  The `*` isn't doing much for you here (just causing you to match zero length groups).

In the other examples having the `*` next to the `[a-z]`, you match adjacent characters of any length.

**EDIT**

Playing around with [this tool](https://www.debuggex.com/) may help.

Comment: I still don't think this really answers why OP looses the `'o'` in 63.  And it's characters of any length > 0 (which is where the empty strings come from).

Comment: Good point about not explaining the `'o'` part, but I think @alastair has that one covered in his comment on his response.  I realized my bug confusing `*` with `+` (for >=0 and >0 matches, respectively) and fixed that.